# Import subfolder file from Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, import, module, jupyter-notebook

With a folder structure like this:

```
~/
 +-- some_module/
 |      +-- subfolder/
 |      |      +-- submodule.py
 |      +-- helpers.py
 |      +-- api.py
 +-- notebook.ipynb
```

This is the content of `api.py`:

```py
from subfolder.submodule import submodule_fun

def print_something(string):
    print(submodule_fun(string))

# ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

And `submodule.py`:

```py
from helpers import helper_fun

def submodule_fun(string):
    stuff = helper_fun(string)
    return stuff
```

This works perfectly fine when running `python api.py` from the command line. The `submodule.py` file is simply using some function from `helpers.py` and no drama needed.

However, I also want to be able to use `submodule.py` from `notebook.ipynb` which lives outside `some_module`. When I add the following lines in this notebook:

```py
from some_module.subfolder import submodule
```

I get the following error:

```
~/some_module/subfolder/submodule.py in <module>

---> from helpers import helper_fun

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'helpers'
```

I tried packaging all of `some_module` into a proper module using `setuptools` but I'm running into weird errors, apparently because the module is not living directly in the repository's root.

Without resorting to packaging `some_module`, would there be a way to be able to access `submodule.py` from the `notebook.ipynb` in this scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `some_module` to your PATH or PYTHONPATH environment variable, either through OS or programatically (shown below)

```
import sys
import os

abspath = r"c:\your\path\to\some_module"
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(abspath ))

from some_module.subfolder import submodule
```

As an alternative to packaging, you can use [`poetry`](https://python-poetry.org/) to manage your dependencies, virtual environment, and it will install your project into the environment without actually needing to produce a package.